# opening page in webbrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I am using TWebBrowser to open a site.

When it opens, it comes with the message that the webbrowser (ie 9) is out of date and that I should replace it. This is the only time I get it.

How can I avoid it (it makes opening the page realy slow)?

Comment: That depends on how the particular site works, doesn't it?

Comment: Don't use Internet Epxlorer aka TWebBrowser for this site. For exampel you can use Google Chrome in Delphi

Comment: @Arioch'The, it depends, twebbrowser is not so bad

Comment: @whosrdaddy my point was not whether it is bad or not. Topicstarter explicitly said that webbrowser does not work for his specific task. Be it good or bad - it does not work. Then for his task another tool to be used..

Comment: what happens if you open this site with IE9 application?

Answer (score 1):

in fact the `TWebBrowser` is showing the page in `IE7 mode` by default. You need to add registry keys for your application to force a higher IE mode.

Complete Doc can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

Answer (score 0):

Websites use User-agent to determine what browser you are using.

Take a look at the following article which will show you how to spoof the user-agent making the website believe you have a different browser. You can use that to mask yourself as the latest firefox/chrome/whatever browser.

http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/changing-the-ua-user-agent-of-a-twebbrowser-component/